# Mentor Graphics Xpedition DxDesigner Print

Tags: mentor-pads, dxdesigner

Does anyone know how to fix this? One day my SSD died and after a system restore, I found a clean list of printers. I tried to reinstall MG EE but the problem persists.

[image: Printer list]

Comment: Are there printers showing in your Windows Printers Control Panel?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, Xpedition Layout sees all printers and prints without problems.

Answer (score 1):

This helped for me: 
https://support.sw.siemens.com/en-US/knowledge-base/MG603980 
Solution: 
In Windows 10 Settings> Printers and Scanners, uncheck "Let Windows Manage My Default Printer"

The workaround is to select another printer as the default. For example, set "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" as the default, and now  the printers are listed in Designer, under File> Print

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn off
"Let Windows manage my default printer"